# Google Cloud Datastore: Is multitenancy bringing any performance benefits?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I can't find anything related to performance considerations when it comes to choosing a multitenant architecture with `Cloud Datastore`

- Is there any performance gain when you have a namespace per tenant vs having all tenants sharing the same namespace since all the properties are indexed anyways?
- are the entities within the same namespace collocated?
- is there any gain when the amount of data grows large?

Comment: if you are starting reconsider updating yourself, firestore is the new generation of datastore https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYG-BgXoJFQ&t=1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't consider the namespace with respect to sharding across regions, the app id (`s~app_name`) is the entire prefix used to determine splitting/replication, and appid data is kept within the same geo as the ~ prefix; in this case America (`s~`). All entities/namespaces will have similar performance characteristics under that appid.

No gain as the Datastore grows.

tl;dr Namespaces are a mechanism to simplify your multi-tenant management and are a feature of the SDK. They also help with selective [export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_entities). They of course allow [scoping of the queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_entities) (for data segregation between tenants), but composite indexes are shared among all namespaces.